# How to set specific path for Linux, MacBook and Windows using python

Tags: python, pypi

I have published this package [codesnip](https://pypi.org/project/codesnip/) on pypi. There is one major issue in the package which is the file created to save the snippets is created where code snip command is called. i.e. Path is not global. How can I make the path global for all operating systems? is there a way to create a specific path and always store it there? e.g. create a folder codesnip at root? or something similar?

Comment: Maybe use the `tempfile` package or just create a directory that is relative to the module?

Comment: @Griffin ill try creating a directory that is relative to the module and Thanks!

Comment: So I changed filename = 'code_snippet_datastorage_file' to filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'code_snippet_datastorage_file') and tried to install it locally and run it at different locations but it doesn't work. can you help me how I can make it such that its relative to where its installed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but this solution works. I used a modules path joined to the filename. This way the file path is always same for the machine.

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(module_name.__file__),'datastorefilename')
```